# An If statement that finds if a number field is left blank or has too many decimal places but ignores if only zeroes in decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I have this one line of code:

```
if ($val === "" || ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2)
```

Thanks to some help from the good people here. But this line of code counts numbers over 2 decimal places even if the numbers are all zeroes.

The problem with this is people can add 2.00 which is fine but not 2.000 which is the same number. So I am looking to add one more || statement that allows people to add multiple zero decimal places.

The entire code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkLength").each(function() {
      $val = $(this).val();
      if ($val === "" || ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) {    
        $(this).popover({
          html: true, 
          placement: "bottom",  
          content: '<textarea class="popover-textarea"></textarea>',
          template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div>'+
              '<div class="row"><div class="col-3 my-auto"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle" id="invalid-input7">'+
              '</i></div><div class="popover-content col-9">Enter a value between 2 and 50 m with up to 2 decimal places.'+
              '</div></div>' 
        });
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(this).click( function() {
            $(this).popover("hide");
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

It checks a number input for validity, if the field is blank, a popover tells them and the script stops there. If the field has too many decimal places, the poppver tells them and the script stops there. But, the problem now lies with the fact that people can add multiple zero decimal places, the script doesn't stop, but the popover still pops up.

Looking forward to your help on this one, it's been troubling me a while.

Comment: Parse the input as a float and then convert it back to a string. That will remove trailing zeroes.

Comment: Could you show me how that is done in this statement, I do understand what you mean, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: And I also don'¨t want to take away the opportunity for 2 decimal places either, it's only if they have a non-zero in the decimals and the number of places exceeds 2.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a float before checking it, as this will discard trailing zeroes after the decimal point. Then use a regular expression to check for too many digits after the decimal. You can also use `isNaN` to check if it's not a number at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCalculation").click(function() {
    $(".checkLength").each(function() {
      const $val = $(this).val();
      let valid = true;
      const valFloat = parseFloat($val);
      if (isNaN(valFloat)) {
        valid = false;
      } else if (/\.\d{3}/.test(valFloat.toString())) {
        valid = false;
      }
      if (!valid) {
        console.log("Invalid input");
      } else {
        console.log("Valid input");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="checkLength">
<button id="submitCalculation">Check</button>
```

Comment: Is this missing a bracket or something somewhere? I am not really familiar with these expressions yet.

Comment: I did try this:

 const rex = /^\s*(?:\d+|0)(?:\.\d{0,2}0*)?\s*$/;
      if (rex.test($val)) {

But for some reason the way I have it, it just isn't working. The popover still pops up on 10.00000 for instance.

Comment: @Barmar, please have a look at my snippet. I tested your method but it seems to get it wrong in 4 cases.

Comment: I fixed the missing parenthesis

Comment: I've updated the answer to use my initial suggestion of converting to a float.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```js
console.log("my answer:","1.2345,0.0103,4.56,2.3400,123.22000,234"
.split(",").map(val=>{
  let m=val.match(/\.\d\d(.*)/);
  return val+': '+!!(m&&m[1]>0) 
}) );

// the following is Barmar's method which gets it wrong in 4 cases:
console.log("Barmar's answer:","1.2345,0.0103,4.56,2.3400,123.22000,234"
.split(",").map(val=>
  val+': '+!!(val == "" || val.match(/\.\d{0,2}[1-9]+/))) );
```

In your script you would need to replace

```
$val = $(this).val(); 
if ($val === "" || ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2) { ...
```

with

```
$val = $(this).val(); 
let m=$val.match(/\.\d\d(.*)/);
if (!!(m&&m[1]>0)) { ...
```

Comment: This seems like it is throwing the correct answers (in reverse in my mind). 

But how do I add that into this line: ($val === "" || ($val.split(".")[1] || "").length > 2)